# Regex replace multiple punctuation in python

Tags: python, regex

I would like to find multiple occurrences of exclamation marks, question marks and periods (such as `!!?!`, `...?`, `...!`) and replace them with just the final punctuation.

i.e. `!?!?!?` would become `?`

and `....!` would become `!`

Is this possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
text = re.sub(r'[\?\.\!]+(?=[\?\.\!])', '', text)
```

That is, remove any sequence of `?!.` characters that are going to be followed by another `?!.` character.

`[...]` is a character class. It matches any character inside the brackets.

`+` means "1 or more of these".

`(?=...)` is a lookahead. It looks to see what is going to come next in the string.

Answer (score 1):

```
text = re.search('[.?!]*([.?!])', text).group(1)
```

The way this works is that the parentheses create a *capture group*, allowing you to access the matched text via the `group` function.